# Sound distortion from microphone or amplifier etc. - what do we call it?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, nouns, adjectives

I live near a temple and during the morning prayer, more often than not, the loudspeaker would produce a jarring sound.

> Is there a single word for the **sound distortion** **from micrphone or amplifier.**

Comment: It's usually just referred to metonymically as _feedback_.

Comment: Distortion is called "distortion".  Feedback (a squealing sound that's usually much more annoying) is called "feedback".

Comment: Possibly related at Music.SE: *[Why are speakers howling when a microphone comes in front of the speaker boxes?](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20666)*

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I guess I don't get why you say "metonymically".  Feedback is called feedback because that's what it is -- the feeding back of sound from speaker to microphone.

Comment: sound distortion relates to the sense of electronic feedback.

Comment: @Hot Licks What you hear is the final sound output from the speakers after perhaps multiple feedback cycles. WhatRoughBeast gives the terms _feedback howl_ and _feedback squeal_ where the sounds are described literally.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - But "feedback" is the technical term, because sound is feeding back.  The identical term is used with "operational amplifiers" where "positive feedback" or (more often) "negative feedback" may be applied (via electronic circuitry) to control the characteristics of the amplifier.

Comment: According to Collins, 'Feedback (Telecommunications) the return of part of the sound output by a loudspeaker to the microphone or pick-up so that a high-pitched whistle is produced'. This differs from the AHDEL definition 'Sound created when a transducer, such as a microphone or the pickup of an electric guitar, picks up sound from a speaker connected to an amplifier and regenerates it back through the amplifier.' They have extended the definition to disguise the metonym. (See 'Is a dead metaphor still a metaphor?')

Comment: ??? How do those two definitions differ?  Explain it in a way that a dumb electrical engineer can understand.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I don't see a functional difference in those definitions either.  They both clearly refer to the *loop* inherent in feedback, which doesn't sound like what the OP is describing (a minor form may be heard as ringing after a loud sound).

Comment: @Hotlicks The principal meaning of the word feedback is 'that which feeds back / is fed back, or the process involved' not 'a resulting phenomenon'. The term is also used for a resulting phenomenon, at least when it's the horrible sound/s we're referring to here; that's a metonymic usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will depend on just exactly what kind of "jarring noise" you're referring to.

The most common is a high-pitched, very loud sound which persists until the microphone is moved or the volume is reduced. This is **feedback**, **feedback howl**, or **feedback squeal**.

Sometimes it's a scraping sound caused by moving the microphone, and the contact with the supporting surface causes noise. This is called **microphonics**.

Sometimes it's caused by wind blowing on the microphone (and can often be cured by placing a foam cover over the microphone), and this is called **wind pop**.

Sometimes it's caused by the speaker or singer speaking or singing too loudly, and that's **overload** or **clipping**.

Sometimes it's caused by a bad connection, and is usually called **static**. If the bad connection is caused by a particular position of the microphone or wires it can be momentary or intermittent (and very hard to track down).

Sometimes it's caused by line-frequency electrical noise, and that's called **hum**. If it only happens occasionally, it's called **intermittent hum**. As with static, it may be caused by a certain position of the wires or microphone, and only last a short time.

Comment: The answer was already in the comments above.

Comment: @weakphoneme It's perfectly acceptable to concoct an answer from comments.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, coming from you, now I agree : )-

Comment: This may be outside the normal scope of ELU as technobabble, but it is really useful. Thank you.

Comment: @weakphoneme - As far as I know, only 3 possible types of "jarring sound" source had been mentioned, but there was no confirmation from the poster that he was satisfied. So I included all the types I could think of. And he still hasn't given a better description.

Comment: +1 for clipping: that fits "jarring"/"distortion" in the Q much better than feedback.  With an enthusiastic speaker/singer and over-amplification (possibly at both pre- and power-amp stages) coupled with cheap PA horn speakers this is exactly what you'll get.  [Example on youtube (also lots of background noise)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQlIt3hQxGY) -- though we don't know what the OP means by temple.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally referred to as :

[Static-buzzing and humming noise](http://www.instructables.com/id/Quick-Fix-Get-Rid-of-BuzzingHumming-Noise-When-U/)

Buzzing:

> - noisy like the sound of a bee.

Humming:

> - like a continuous droning sound of a bee on the wing; buzz.

Answer (score 0):

"Noise", in a sound system, is when, without any intended input, one can hear a hiss, hum, or other sound (perhaps a radio static type sound).

"Distortion", in a sound system, is when the reproduction of sound is not "true".  The sound coming out may sound "staticy" and muffled, even though there is no noticeable "noise" when there is no input.

"Feedback", in a sound system, is when sound from the loudspeaker "feeds back" into the microphone (or occasionally due to crossed wires), producing whistle or loud squeal.

All three terms are technical terms in the electronic trades, with essentially the same meanings as above, only applicable to other situations.